# Redis : Logging query outputs

Tags: go, redis

I have found that a redis application is returning, from its REST API (which uses a redis library), the **wrong** result (0, instead of 5).

In my code for running this query via Go, I run:

```
println("LLEN HANDLER")
infoL := HandleError(pool.Get(0).Do("LLEN","xyz")).(int64)
lengthJSON := HandleError(json.MarshalIndent(infoL, "", " ")).([]byte)
print("RETURN LEN = "+string(lengthJSON))
rw.Write(lengthJSON)
```

This returns 0.

**However, if I run the query from redis-cli (on slaves, or on master)**

```
LLEN xyz
```

I get the **correct** result. The result is 5.

In particular, I'm using https://github.com/xyproto/simpleredis , and I noticed that in the same app, all queries of the form:

```
list := simpleredis.NewList(pool, key)
//members := HandleError(list.GetAll()).([]string)
members := HandleError(list.GetLastN(4)).([]string)
```

work normally and return non-null data, which confirms that the network connectivity etc in the system is working.

Comment: have you tried printing `infoL`  or the redis response directly?

Comment: sounds to me like the client is working against the wrong db number

Comment: iirc , my print debugging was not informative, but I can double check.

Comment: is there any chance that this is related to changes from 2.6 -> 2.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

simpleredis runs a `SELECT [dbindex]` command before running the query.

Does it work if you run `SELECT` before `LLEN`?